# Несколько функций def. Одна переменная в них

Tags: python, функции

В моем коде я беру данные с API сайта, которые постоянно обновляются. Я получаю нужную инфу my_info. Затем есть две функции def func1() и def func2(), в которых мне нужно использовать актуальное my_info для расчетов.

Как это записать?

```
my_info = request.get(www...)
def func1():
    my_info * 2
def func2():
    my_info * 3
func1()
func(2)
```

Этот вариант не работает, так как my_info посчиталось один раз после запуска кода и не меняется все время, а должно меняться! Т.е. данные получаются не актуальными. Я не использовал пока return, не знаю, как правильно записать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные постоянно обновляются, то вам нужно постоянно обращаться к API.

```
def func1(my_info):
    return my_info * 2


def func2(my_info):
    return my_info * 3


while True: # бесконечный цикл
    my_info = request.get(www...) # получаем инфу от API
    my_info_1, my_info_2 = func1(my_info), func2(my_info) # записываем в переменные my_info_1, my_info_2 результат работы функций func1(my_info), func2(my_info), соостветственно
    #далее делайте с этими переменными что хотите
```